# Issue Customizing ParseQueryAdapter

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am building a friend request view of an application. I'm trying to display a list of friend requests That you can accept by clicking on them.

Here is my code I run in the `onCreate()` method of the activity. As you can see, I need a ListView item for each friend request object to the current user, which I build into the `QueryAdapter`. I want to set the image and text of each ListView friend request item to the `profileImageMedium` and `username` fields of the user who sent the friend request. Each friend request object points to a `fromUser` who sent the request.

The problem is that the `setTextKey()` and `setImageKey()` methods won't work for these keys since they are keys of an object pointed to by the friend request. What's the best way to set the text and image keys to these fields

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_friend_request);

    // Instantiate ParseQueryAdapter
    final ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> friendRequestListAdapter =
            new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
                public ParseQuery<ParseObject> create() {
                    // Here we can configure a ParseQuery to our heart's desire.
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> friendRequestQuery = new ParseQuery("FriendRequests");
                    friendRequestQuery.whereEqualTo("toUser", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                    friendRequestQuery.include("fromUser");

                    return friendRequestQuery;
                }
            });

    // Set as adapter for our listview
    ListView friendRequestListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friendRequestListView);
    friendRequestListView.setOnItemClickListener(friendRequestClickedHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution for you is to create subclass of **ParseQueryAdapter** and override `getItemView()` method.  Just like this:

```
class QueryAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter {
    public QueryAdapter(Context context, ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<T> queryFactory) {
        super(context, queryFactory, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (null == v) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.your_layout, null);
        }
        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_view_id);
        ParseUser fromUser = object.getParseUser("fromUser");
        name.setText(fromUser.getString("username");
        !-- Load your image here
    }
}
```

I don't know how you're loading images, but you got an idea - if your **profileImageMedium** is URL then use some image loading library such as Picasso, or if it is ParseFile change ImageView in your cell to ParseImageView and call

```
image.setParseFile(file);
image.loadInBackground();
```

Then in your Activity change ParseQueryAdapter to your QueryAdapter and don't forget to set your QueryAdapter to the ListView

```
friendRequestListView.setAdapter(QueryAdapter);
```

Comment: Perfect! I skimmed over that in the Android docs at first and for some reason didn't think it was for me. But your explanation helped me figure out how to apply it. Thanks!